# Python: Catching an exception works outside of a function but not inside a function

Tags: python, exception

I have a strange problem which I can't solve myself.

If I execute `outside_func.py` in two separate terminals, the second execution catches the BlockingIOError exception and the message is printed:

**outside_func.py**

```
import fcntl
import time

# Raise BlockingIOError if same script is already running.
try:
    lockfile = open('lockfile', 'w')
    fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except BlockingIOError:
    print('Script already running.')

time.sleep(20)
```

If I do the same with `inside_func.py` nothing is caught and no message is printed:

**inside_func.py**

```
import fcntl
import time

# Raise BlockingIOError if same script is already running.
def script_already_running():
    try:
        lockfile = open('lockfile', 'w')
        fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except BlockingIOError:
        print('Script already running.')

script_already_running()

time.sleep(20)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with something you changed outside of the posted code that you didn't realize was important.

Comment: I updated the examples. Now the problem should be reproducible.

Comment: Something isn't right, inside_func.py, caught both messages!

Comment: This is really strange. There is nothing else in my file than what you see here and I get another result.. Btw I use python 3.4.3

Comment: if you move the sleep inside the function do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: If I put `sleep` into the function after the except-block I do get the exception like I should. But this does not really enlighten me :)

Comment: If I replace `time.sleep()` with `shutil.copyfile(src, dest)` I get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is closed when you leave the function so the two snippets are not the same, in the code snippet where the try is *outside of a function* there is still a reference to the file object in the scope of the sleep call so further calls to open the *lockfile* rightfully error. If you change the function by  moving the sleep inside the function you will see the error raised as now you have comparable code:

```
import fcntl
import time

# Raise BlockingIOError if same script is already running.
def script_already_running():
    try:
        lockfile = open('lockfile', 'w')
        fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except BlockingIOError:
        print('except')
    sleep(20)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix the function in order to keep the `flock` *alive*?

Comment: I got it :) I let the function return the `lockfile`, that seems to solve the problem.