# Python filename, not markup. open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have changed my Python 2.7 routine to accept a file path as a parameter for the routine so I don't have to duplicate code by inserting multiple file paths inside the method.

When my method is called I get the following error:

```
looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.
  '"%s" looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.' % markup)
```

My method implementation is:

```
def extract_data_from_report3(filename):
    html_report_part1 = open(filename,'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(filename, "html.parser")
    th = soup.find_all('th')
    td = soup.find_all('td')

    headers = [header.get_text(strip=True) for header in soup.find_all("th")]
    rows = [dict(zip(headers, [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")]))
        for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:-1]]
    print(rows)
    return rows
```

To call the method is as follows:

```
rows_part1 =  report.extract_data_from_report3(r"E:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport_part1.html")
print "part1 = "
print rows_part1
```

How can I pass the file name as a parameter?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to pass a file handle then don't call read, just pass `open(filename)` or the file handle without calling read :

```
def extract_data_from_report3(filename):
    html_report_part1 = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup( html_report_part1, "html.parser")
```

Or:

```
def extract_data_from_report3(filename):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser")
```

You can pass `html_report_part1` after calling read as suggested but you don't need to, BeautifulSoup can take a file object.

Comment: Does BeautifulSoup dispose the file or should it be inside a with block instead?

Comment: @Mephy, once you leave the function the file would almost certainly be closed, if there were no references to the file object it would be closed after reading, you can see it in this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220460/python-catching-an-exception-works-outside-of-a-function-but-not-inside-a-funct/37221812#37221812. It would be no harm to use a with block but not really needed.

Answer (score 5):

You should pass actual content of the file which you have read to `BeautifulSoup` :

```
html_report_part1 = open(filename,'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part1, "html.parser")
```